# Matplotlib Animation for Plotting Points Being Connected Given Arrays of X and Y values to be coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I have two arrays containing x and y values. Each array has 1274 values in it. I essentially want to create a matplotlib animation where these points are being plotted and also connected by a line. I tried doing this with FuncAnimation, but ran into a lot of trouble. Imagine that x and y are the two arrays that I'm referring to. Rest of the code is what I tried so far.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from os import getcwd, listdir


gif_path = getcwd() + "/gifs"



fig = plt.figure()
graph, = plt.plot([], [], 'o')

def animate(i):
    if i > len(x) - 1:
        i = len(x) - 1
    graph.set_data(x[:i+1], y[:i+1])
    return graph

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=200)
ani.save(f"{gif_path}/sample_region.gif", writer="imagemagick")
```

Any help would kindly be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be following [an example from `matplotlib`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/animation_api.html), you just need a few extra changes:

```
x = range(100)
y = np.random.rand(100)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(0, 100)
ax.set_ylim(0, 1)
graph, = plt.plot([], [], '-')

def init():
    return graph,

def animate(i):
    graph.set_data(x[:i],y[:i])
    return graph,

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=range(len(x)), interval=50, save_count=len(x),
                    init_func=init, blit=True)
ani.save('ani.gif', writer='PillowWriter')
```

This produces [this GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9k0IN.jpg).  The changes are:

- set up an `Axes` on `fig` with set axis limits
- change the `o` to `-`
- add an `init` function for initializing the animation
- add a `frames` argument to pass indexes used to select data
- update `animate` to handle those `frames`

But I tried making this with an array of 1200 points, and it didn't seem like my computer could complete it... You can try but you might need to trim the data or plot more data each frame.